# Do we want a post notice for questions where people are using equipment in ways that are clearly incorrect or dangerous?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to get a site-specific post notice (e.g., [Request for a new post notice for The Workplace: "sensitive topic / be nice"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301760/request-for-a-new-post-notice-for-the-workplace-sensitive-topic-be-nice)) that can either alert users to proper site behavior or tell future users important information?

For instance, I'm thinking a post notice would be in order on questions about people making bad or dangerous choices about equipment. An example would be [Knots when abseiling with single rope](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19486/knots-when-abseiling-with-single-rope), where uncertified equipment is being used in situations that certified equipment should be used, and where certified equipment is clearly being used in ways that it should not be.

I propose the wording to be something like:

> Inappropriate use of certified equipment and use of uncertified equipment may result in death.

Comment: Same feels when I see medications being suggested in answers for altitude sickness :/

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we need a post notice. The Q&A process already has all the neccesary tools.

- If the question is outright dangerous in itself (e.g. asking for medication "recommendations"), it is most often off-topic -> close it.
- If the question contains a misconception or obviously dangerous intent, an answer can/needs to address that. Write that answer if you can ;)
- If an answer doesn't address the point above, don't upvote just because upvoting is nice or there is no other answer or ... We have a (usually) really nice voting pattern on TGO, but sometimes it is too nice. Don't upvote an answer that doesn't really address all key points of a question and downvote answers that are lacking. Don't restrict downvotes to downright wrong/bad answers. If you want to be nice (yeiii!), leave a constructive comment and revisit your vote if the answer gets edited.
- If an answer doesn't address the question at all or is intentionally misleading, flag it as not an answer. Only do it in these cases, if you "just" believe it's factually wrong, that flag is not appropriate - a downvote is.

Actually the above explains what you can do without the notice, but it is no reason not to have such a notice. I don't have any important arguments against it. The only one is, that it is one more piece in the puzzle to handle (you somehow need to decide when it is appropriate to use) and I think it's potentially more hassle than use.

Answer (score 3):

Do we want to **mark questions about things we think are crazy/stupid/ridiculous?**

As opposed to say nicely spelling out why it's not a good idea to use a tourniquet after a rattlesnake bite for example?

I am **not worried about misconceptions/mistakes/silly ideas in questions, we have unlimited answers to correct them** and make the internet a better place in the meantime.

On the other hand, sometimes people upvote [answers](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/17462/8794) for that lack sources and may be harmful and incorrect and in those cases, the Requires Sources Notice would probably be a good thing.

For examples of dangerous posts

- https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/16777/ Was live for around 4 months
- https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/16726 Was live for at least 8 months

In both of those cases, having the notice in place would probably speed the process up.

Comment: I think my use of crazy/stupid/ridiculous was unfortunate. I was thinking more of a limited case where equipment was being used incorrectly or incorrect equipment was being used.

Comment: @Sue go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the number of meta posts about opening and closing questions.  If the community can not agree on what is in scope how would they agree on what is "Inappropriate use of certified equipment"

Both Charlie and Imsodin have good answers to the question.